# How to calculate actual ocean water height, taking into account both tides and weather?

Tags: resource-recommendations, oceanography

Tide tables are useful starting points for tides-- whcih are arguably the dominant first-order effect in water depth changes. However, a not-to-distant second-order effect is the weather. Wind will push water levels higher or lower, as will atmospheric highs and lows. A third-order effect is rain, especially if it causes a nearby river to rise.

I'd like to find some published literature which helps account for these deviations from idealized tidal predictions.

(Better would be an already existing model with queryable API, but I'm not confident such a thing exists.)

Comment: In addition to the model you will also need access to a supercomputer on which to run it.

Comment: Land subsidence complicates the determination of ocean height.